# Publish WCF service to live website

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010, publish

I have only been playing w/ wcf stuff for about a week. I have it working on the dev server in Visual Studio, and now I want to put the project on the web. I used publish in Visual Studio to put it up w/ ftp. My FTP client confirms the files are there, but when I enter the address in a browser, I get the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /EquipService.svc

Is there some setting I need to change or some setup I need to do on the server? I don't know why it says the file is unavailable since FileZilla shows the files on the server. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

**EDIT:**
Here is the Web.config, but just as a preface, I don't know what any of this is doing, I just copied bits and pieces from another guys project until the errors stopped and it worked. :|

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior>
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior> 
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataSupport">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix ="localhost"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding">
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="EquipService.svc">
    <endpoint address="~/EquipService.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Equipment.IEquipService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Im still not quite understanding why the services work on the Visual Studio server, and not on a web server.

But thanks for looking.

Comment: It looks like your web server hasn't been configured to contain a web site for the service. The 404 error means the URL address you are sending is not linked to anything on the web server. If that isn't it then you'll need to put the web.config contents in the question to show how you've configured your service to get more detailed help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the WCFTestClient.exe to test your service.

Couple of things that I have learned. Its always good to create a seperate project for Services.

You can create a webservice and it can be consumed in the same web project using the localhost as address.

I had a scenario where I was trying to call it from my website's HTML page using javascript and it didn't work because I created the webservice in the regular webapp. In order to access it from javascript i needed to publish that service over the internet so the javascript can refer to a link (rather than localhost).

Answer (score 1):

Well I did manage to find out the cause of the problem. It was the server. For some reason its physical path was pointing to an incorrect folder, and now the ball is in their court to fix it.

Thanks for the help